# mipsel-linux-ar related compilation error appears in specific fedora core 11

Tags: toolchain, linux-toolchain

I compiled my codebase in a fc11 linux pc and getting following error.

```
Archive: [libexam.a]
Usage: mipsel-linux-ar [emulation options] [-]{dmpqrstx}[abcfilNoPsSuvV] [member-name][count] archive-file file...
mipsel-linux-ar -M [<mri-script]
 commands:
  d            - delete file(s) from the archive
  m[ab]        - move file(s) in the archive
  p            - print file(s) found in the archive
  q[f]         - quick append file(s) to the archive
  r[ab][f][u]  - replace existing or insert new file(s) into the archive
  t            - display contents of archive
  x[o]         - extract file(s) from the archive
 command specific modifiers:
  [a]          - put file(s) after [member-name]
  [b]          - put file(s) before [member-name] (same as [i])
  [D]          - use zero for timestamps and uids/gids
  [N]          - use instance [count] of name
  [f]          - truncate inserted file names
  [P]          - use full path names when matching
  [o]          - preserve original dates
  [u]          - only replace files that are newer than current archive contents
 generic modifiers:
  [c]          - do not warn if the library had to be created
  [s]          - create an archive index (cf. ranlib)
  [S]          - do not build a symbol table
  [T]          - make a thin archive
  [v]          - be verbose
  [V]          - display the version number
 @<file>      - read options from <file>
 emulation options:
  No emulation specific options

 mipsel-linux-ar: supported targets: elf32-tradlittlemips elf32-tradbigmips ecoff-     littlemips ecoff-bigmips elf32-ntradlittlemips elf64-tradlittlemips elf32-ntradbigmips     elf64-tradbigmips elf64-little elf64-big elf32-little elf32-big srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex
make[3]: *** [core/linuxuser.mipsel-uclibc/libexam.a] Error 1
make[2]: *** [default] Error 2
make[1]: *** [build-exam] Error 2
make: *** [app] Error 2
```

Could anyone help me in identifying what is this error meant for?

Note: I mentioned specific because i am getting this error in one specific fc11 pc only. I compared the uname -a between the working and not working pc, both are same. Did any one confirm does it requires for any specific package to be installed for this.

Comment: Should be moved to [Superuser](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: I am in super user mode only. I need some inputs like what is this error refers to.

Comment: Did you try clicking the link? [Superuser](http://superuser.com/) is like stackoverflow but for system related questions. As this is not a programming question it probably does not belong on this site, and was giving you heads up before it got migrated and you lost points.